# Convert C# object to JSON or Javascript object

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, json, razor

I am a C# developer and a newbi in Javascript.
I have one C# object and finally, in index.cshtml, I can get a string converted from the object via calling Json.Encode(obj)

The string is:

```
[
    {
    "Name":"CASE_A",
    "Values":[99.8,99.9,99.9,99.8,99.8,96.3,22.3]
    },
    {
    "Name":"CASE_B",
    "Values":[99.8,99.8,99.8,96.3,22.3]
    },
]
```

However, when I call JSON.parse(@TheString),I got:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &
```

The location of this error shows me this:

```
data = JSON.parse([{&quot;Name&quot;:&quot;CASE_A&quot;,&quot;Values&quot;:[99.8,99.9,99.9,99.8 ....
```

How can I fix this problem?

---

Thank you for the answers!
But still I got an error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
```

For simple testing, I used this:

```
@{
    string tmp = "[{\"Name\":\"CASE_A\",\"Values\":[99.8,99.9,98.6]},{\"Name\":\"CASE_B\",\"Values\":[96.7,11.1]}]";
}
var data1 = JSON.parse(@Html.Raw(@tmp));
```

And source shows this line:

```
var data1 = JSON.parse([{"Name":"CASE_A","Values":[99.8,99.9,98.6]},{"Name":"CASE_B","Values":[96.7,11.1]}]);
```

I cannot see any "o" here.

---

Also, for making javascript object, Travis suggested to remove the key name before serialization. But in C#, all object must have its member name. All I can think of is string manipulation. Is there any better way to do so?

Comment: Ideally, it would be much better if I can get javascipt object without Key Name. e.g., [[CASE_A, [[99.8,99.9,99.9,99.8,99.8,96.3,22.3], ...]

Comment: That should be done *before* you serialize.

Comment: I actually don't figure this error out because of anther error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o". But instead of json object, I used a javascript object and used "data= eval(@Html.Raw(TheString))". It was successful.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Razor will automatically escape HTML entities for you in an attempt to be helpful. You can disable this with [`Html.Raw`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740%28v=vs.108%29.aspx):

```
JSON.parse(@Html.Raw(TheString))
```

Comment: Thank you p.s.w.g. I was wondering between Rahul and you but it seems more people liked your clear answer.

Comment: @Daebarkee Thanks, but keep in mind, you should generally accept the answer which you feel most completely answers your question or resolves your issue, which isn't necessarily the most popular one. See also [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 6):

For your second error, JSON.parse expects a string, but you are passing in an array.  Your outputted js code has to look like this to work:

```
var data1 = JSON.parse("[{\"Name\":\"CASE_A\",\"Values\":[99.8,99.9,98.6]},{\"Name\":\"CASE_B\",\"Values\":[96.7,11.1]}]");
```

I also want to note that since you are injecting this object into your javascript code on the server side, there is no need to call JSON.parse at all.  As long as you send properly formatted javascript to the client where it will be evaluated and run, then it doesn't matter how it's created on the server.  Try this instead:

```
var data1 = @Html.Raw(@tmp);
```

Answer (score 3):

You may try this using **[HtmlHelper.Raw method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)**:-

```
data = JSON.parse(@Html.Raw(TheString));
```

Also check out **[DataContractJsonSerializer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx)**

> Serializes objects to the JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) and
>   deserializes JSON data to objects. This class cannot be inherited.

Comment: Thank you Rahul. But still I have an issue. Please, see the updated question.

Answer (score 1):

Using the string will cause Razor to protect you from injection. If you are passing in json chances are that isn't an issue. Common practice is to use the `Html.Raw` helper

```
data = JSON.parse( @(Html.Raw(TheString)) );
```

Answer (score 0):

OP's solution worked for me as well.

```
data = eval(JSON.parse(@Html.Raw(TheString)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a C# `Object` and want to use it in JavaScript as is, you can do:

```
var jsObject = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(TheString));
```

You'll need to add the `nuget package` and import the `dll` in `_ViewImports.cshtml`:

```
@using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

Hope it helps someone...